# .htaccess rewrite for category with pagination

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a mod-rewrite rule to handle pagination links on my site.

I'd like my URL structure to be this `https://example.com/category.php?name=category-link` to `https://example.com/category/category-link` [without pagination]

and `https://example.com/category.php?name=category-link&page=2` to  `https://example.com/category/category-link/2` [with pagination]

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9]+) category.php?name=$1&page=$2
```

`https://example.com/category/category-link` isn't working

[image: 404 page screenshot]

`https://example.com/category/category-link/1` is working

[image: working page screenshot]

**2. am i able to redirect `localhost/article/4/` to `localhost/article/4` [here 4 is an id]**

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well of course `/category/category-link` won’t work with _that_ rule, because the pattern _demands_ an additional slash after that, and then at least one digit.

Comment: What is the problem here? You've created one rule for the pagination (arguably the more complicated one). Now you need another (similar) rule for the non-pagination link. You don't necessarily need a single rule (otherwise you will _always_ get a `page` URL parameter in the result).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only. Please make sure you clear your browser cache after placing these rules into your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category.php?name=%1 [L]

RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9]+)/? category.php?name=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

OR you could use it without `RewriteCond` too. Make sure you are putting either of these NOT both of them please.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ category.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9]+)/? category.php?name=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: @AlSayeed, your welcome, keep sharing and keep learning on this great forum of learning cheers buddy :)